# How to Append the record in Json File in ASP MVC?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

//This is what I have implemented. This works fine. But the problem, when I again submit the data, the old data remove. Only the last inserted data shown in file.
I want all the data in Json file when we save.

If anyone has idea, please help me.

```
public ActionResult Index(UserData model)
{
      try
      {
            // Pass the "personlist" object for conversion object to JSON string  
            string jsondata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/output.json");
            // Write that JSON to txt file,  
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path , jsondata);
            TempData["msg"] = "Json file Generated! check this in your App_Data folder";
      }
      catch (Exception e) { }
            
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
```

Comment: Your code *is* saving all the data and overwriting the file. Did you want to *append* data to the file perhaps? You can use `FIle.AppendAllText` but that will produce an invalid JSON file - JSON can't have multiple root elements.

Comment: Are you trying to store a separate JSON payload per line perhaps? You'd have to serialize the data without newlines first. I'm not sure the obsolete `JavaScriptSerializer` can do that. Everyone, including Microsoft, is using Json.NET instead, with eg `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.None)`, then use `AppendLine` to add a new line to the file

Comment: {"FirstName":"Himanshu ","LastName":"Mishra","OfficeName":"Hashtag Labs","Email":"himanshu@gmail.com","Phone":"9988775544","RoleId":0,"RoleName":null}

This is my Data. I want to save another data keep this also in the file. So, what's the solution?

Comment: That comment doesn't explain anything. The current code saves all the data in a single file, so the question by itself is unclear. It would make sense if the real problem was how to *append* records to a file

Comment: Yeah, give me solution for save multiple records or append records inn json file?

Comment: Edit the question to clearly ask what you actually want. BTW I already wrote how to do this in a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your implementation of UserData, so I took a guess at what it might look like based on your comment. You need to read back the contents of the file if it exists before overwriting it. I use Json.NET and have never used this particular serializer that you are using, but I'm assuming it works. You could do something like this:

```
public class UserData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string OfficeName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(UserData model)
{
    try
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/output.json");
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonData;
        List<UserData> userDataList = new List<UserData>();

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Read from existing file.
            jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

            // Fill in the list with the existing user data.
            userDataList.AddRange(serializer.Deserialize<List<UserData>>(jsonData));
        }

        // Add the new user data to the end of the list.
        userDataList.Add(model);

        // Generate JSON based on the complete list.
        jsonData = serializer.Serialize(userDataList);

        // Write that JSON to a file.
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, jsonData);
        TempData["msg"] = "Json file Generated! check this in your App_Data folder";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```